# Estimation of model with non linear dependent variable

Tags: estimation, independence, nonlinear, variable

I am trying to verify whether two variables are linked by a relation of the type: |y|=a*x or y^2=a*x.

What could be the right statistical procedure to verify whether the above relations are correct and to estimate the parameter a?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of these are still linear models, so OLS still works fine. Nonlinear least squares is only necessary when your dependent variable depends nonlinearly on the model parameters.

The same logic applies for why we can estimate the model 
$$\ln{y}=a+bx$$
using OLS, i.e. because the model is linear in the parameters.

An example of a model that would require nonlinear least squares would be
$$y=a+cx^b.$$